On Christmas holidays mother gets to the hospital for addicts, and her children celebrate holidays with another woman and fall in love with her
I am looking for a movie i watched in childhood, so i guess it was filmed before 2000.
The action takes place on Christmas Day (or on New Year Day). Addict woman has children, but she has to go to the hospital for addicts. Her children celebrate holidays with another woman (maybe with their aunt, or with their mom's friend).
When mother comes back home, she understand, that her children love that woman more than her.

@Richard thank you very much!!
